# Sharing data from static lib between dynamic libs

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qtcore

I have next situation:

1. Static library with **class A**; (logger)
2. Main application which creates **class A** instance as singleton
3. Different delay loaded dynamic libraries (plugins) that links with (**1.**) and need to use instance of **class A**.

How should I share singleton from main application (**2.**) between plugins (**3.**)? Are there any features in Qt / C++ to do this?

Currently I'm using ugly solution based on shared memory and I don't think that it is right.

I'm thinking about refactoring with using of dependency injection pattern but it imposes some restrictions.

SAMPLE:

Static library "log.lib":

```
struct Log
{
  void write( QString text );
};
```

Main application "app.exe":

```
Log *logger = new Log; // I need only one logger for all application 

int main()
{
  logger->write( "Main" );
  ...
}
```

Plugin 1 "plg1.dll"

```
extern Log *logger; // Logger from "app.exe"
void Foo()
{
  logger->write( "Foo" );
}
```

Plugin 2 "plg2.dll"

```
extern Log *logger; // Logger from "app.exe"
void Bar()
{
  logger->write( "Bar" );
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, please paste some code. If I understand correctly which I am not sure about, you may wish to instantiate the singleton from your library, perhaps through the plugin interface, but what sharing you are writing about.... remains unclear to me, so does how it is related to using a library statically.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. But I don't want to instantiate *logger* throught library interface because there a lot of intricate relations between libraries (Shared / Static / Delay loaded / mixed cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so in order:

- You seem not to use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for singleton use cases.
- Your original question is not much related to Qt.
- This has little to nothing to do with the distinction of static library or not.
- You could make the plugin interface accept a logger mutator so that you could then set that with the instance from the application.

I would personally just use the singleton pattern properly, and the plugin could also query the very instance. Please take a look at the following Qt macro:

> [Q_GLOBAL_STATIC( Type, VariableName)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qglobalstatic.html#Q_GLOBAL_STATIC)
>
> Creates a global and static object of type QGlobalStatic, of name VariableName and that behaves as a pointer to Type. The object created by Q_GLOBAL_STATIC initializes itself on the first use, which means that it will not increase the application or the library's load time. Additionally, the object is initialized in a thread-safe manner on all platforms.

You could easily build the singleton pattern on top of it, and actually this would be even thread-safe.

Here you can find another example not using `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC`, but `QObject` inheritance and facilitates the job with `QCoreApplication` that we implemented in our project.

https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/games/gluon/repository/revisions/master/entry/core/singleton.h

This version above is also-thread safe.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That solves everything. P.S. Sorry for bad English, I'm working on it ;)